# ubuntu 12.4 LTS dualboot with windows xp not working

Tags: dual-boot

Since I loaded ubuntu 12.4 LTS I can no longer get into windows XP. When I boot the computer Windows XP goes through its sequence until it shows boot from CD/DVD then the screen comes up to chose ubuntu or windows xp but the arrow keys do not respnd and ubuntu opens. Also I am not sure if I need the 320 updates the update manager says are available. They will not install anyway. I am a rookie when it comes to computers. What are my options? I would like to have a dual boot computer with ubuntu and windows xp. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem with windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10. Your Windows Bootloader has been overwritten by Ubuntu its. With a windows xp recovery cd you can reinstall the windows xp boatloader

Comment: Downvote: His problems seems to be related to keys not working, not with bootloaders problems (i.e. if he can get the arrow key to work he will be able to boot Windows). Also, your answer is not really useful for a novice, you should tell him how to use the windows recovery cd.

Comment: My keyboard works fine everywhere but in the grub window.

Comment: Someone from lauch pad gave me the answer to my problem which was I had to enable keyboard support in the Bios of my computer and now the arrows keys work in the grub installer window.